# Persistent Countdown Timer for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, gui, timer

I'm looking for a countdown timer application that persists between restarts and takes away time if the PC turns off.

For example, I'd like to be able to set an alarm for 27 hours. 3 hours later I turn my computer off for 12 hours and then turn it back on. I would then like the alarm to go off automatically (sound or popup, I don't mind) 12 hours later.

Preferably I would like to not have the timer in my taskbar, though in the tray is fine.

The main aspect of this application is it must be persistent and account for time when the application is not open. If I have to set it to start with Windows that is fine. I don't mind if the application is open-source, but it would preferably be freeware and NOT a web-app.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the exact thing you want but have a look at [Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/) with [this skin](http://customize.org/rainmeter/skins/64518).

What Rainmeter does is displaying totally customizable widgets on your desktop (you can also have them displayed in front of the taskbar, although it is different from being windows in the taskbar or background apps in the tray) and the possibilities are endless. You can therefore **make countdown widgets and as people have already done it**, you can just download them and customize them as you like.

Rainmeter starts with Windows but this is can be disabled. One started, it runs in the tray.

The skin I provided lets you chose a countdown time in hours:minutes:seconds and then displays the remaining time. It should not reset when restarting either Rainmeter or your PC.

The cool thing is, as I said, if you are a little comfortable with getting your hands dirty, you can edit the widget or make one from scratch to fully match your needs.

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: I didn't think of Rainmeter, that's a great idea, thank you. I'll leave the question up for a couple days to see if gains any more answers.